# Tell vsftpd to log to stdout instead of some file

Tags: linux, vsftpd

By default, `vsftpd` logs to `/var/log/vsftpd.log`. `stdout` stays empty when started in foreground and I would like to utilize it so that it is easier. I don't really need to store the logs either. Help?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
vsftpd -xferlog_enable=YES -vsftpd_log_file=$(tty)
```

**Explanation:**

from [man vsftpd.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/vsftpd.conf):

> **vsftpd_log_file**
> This option is the name of the file to which we write the vsftpd style log file. This log is only written if the option xferlog_enable is set, and xferlog_std_format is NOT set. Alternatively, it is written if you have set the option dual_log_enable. One further complication - if you have set syslog_enable, then this file is not written and output is sent to the system log instead.
> Default: /var/log/vsftpd.log

I suggest you to take a look both at [man vsftpd.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/vsftpd.conf) and at [man vsftpd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vsftpd). You will find a full detailed explanation of how this tool work.

Comment: That logs to the terminal (assuming there is one) rather then to _stdout_.

Comment: @roaima I assumed he/she meant to the terminal because he/she said that `vsftpd` started in foreground

Comment: Yes, I meant in a terminal. Can I put the `$(tty)` in the configuration file (/etc/vsftpd.conf)?

Comment: If the file exists you could log to `/dev/stdout`

Comment: @shards no you can't, that's because the conf file doesn't do the command substitution. If you want to put those options in the configuration file and the file `/dev/stdout` exists, you can log there, like roaima said.

Comment: I put `/dev/stdout` in the configuration file, no luck.

Comment: @shards since you can not predict what "standard output" means in any given context, I don't think you can set the conf file to work the way you want. If you don't want to set the configuration on the command line like shown before, you could use `tail -f /var/log/vsftpd.log` to see the log in real time.